# Spring Cloud Zuul Reverse Proxy doesnt fetch data from CouchDB when URL encoded

Tags: tomcat, couchdb, spring-cloud, url-encoding, netflix-zuul

(UPDTED)

I created a Spring cloud Reverse proxy using [spring-cloud-starter-zuul](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/) to forward all pouchDB-CouchDB requests through my proxy. and it forward all requests that are like `http://10.16.33.221:8080/couchdb/**`.
Here is my `application.properties` file

```
zuul.routes.couchdb.url=http://10.16.32.85:5984/

ribbon.eureka.enabled=false

server.port=8080
```

*`10.16.32.85:5984` is CouchDB address.*

The problem occurred when pouchDB - CouchDB sync requests are forwarding. I found some URL-encoded `Options` and `Get` requests are sending by pouch DB as like follows *(forward slash '/' is encoded to %2F)*

```
http://10.16.33.221:8080/couchdb/inspection/RailCar%2Fbdbc936f-2c33-46f8-b037-ffa329aa4886?revs=true&latest=true&open_revs=%5B%227-fc6370e4d1cecca0fcc103b0e2763e1e%22%5D&_nonce=1483422848386
```

*`http://10.16.33.221:8080` is my proxy and `inspection` is DB name.*

I found Those requests are throwing by apache tomcat due to the security issue. And as suggested [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1583) I added suggested configuration to allow encoded URLs to my Spring application. Then encoded URLs came to my application but doesn't get the response after forwarding that.

For an example,

When I send following requests,

```
http://10.16.33.221:8080/couchdb/inspection/_changes?since=551
```

this gives required result. this request sending to CouchDB through my spring application(proxy). That means my proxy is working fine.

```
http://10.16.33.221:8080/couchdb/inspection/RailCar%2Fbdbc936f-2c33-46f8-b037-ffa329aa4886?revs=true&latest=true&open_revs=%5B%227-fc6370e4d1cecca0fcc103b0e2763e1e%22%5D&_nonce=1483422848386
```

this gives 404 not found as HTTP status. This request coming to the proxy but doest fetch result after forwarding it to the CouchDB.

But if I send the same URL to CouchDB directly as follows,

```
http://10.16.32.85:5984/inspection/RailCar%2fbdbc936f-2c33-46f8-b037-ffa329aa4886?revs=true&latest=true&open_revs=%5B%227-fc6370e4d1cecca0fcc103b0e2763e1e%22%5D&_nonce=1483422848386
```

It gives the requird response and 200 HTTP status.

But If I send the same URL with decoded forward slash to the CouchDB directly as follows

```
http://10.16.32.85:5984/inspection/RailCar/bdbc936f-2c33-46f8-b037-ffa329aa4886?revs=true&latest=true&open_revs=%5B%227-fc6370e4d1cecca0fcc103b0e2763e1e%22%5D&_nonce=1483422848386
```

it also gives 404 not found as HTTP status. Now I am confused what is going wrong and what I have to do. This problem wasted my whole week. So please give me any suggestion to overcome this.

updated-->
I used the jetty server to deploy the web application and for jetty no need to allow encoded forward slash. So I removed that configuration. Then encoded URLs like

```
http://10.16.33.221:8080/couchdb/inspection/RailCar%2Fbdbc936f-2c33-46f8-b037-ffa329aa4886?revs=true&latest=true&open_revs=%5B%227-fc6370e4d1cecca0fcc103b0e2763e1e%22%5D&_nonce=1483422848386
```

are coming to my proxy without any configuration for the encoded slash but, after forwarding, those also give 404 not found.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the point what is going wrong. jetty and tomcat decodes the servlet path of the incoming URL and forwards them. But still, no solution for overcoming this problem. have to re-encode the servlet path using a filter or whatever. But incoming Http servlet request can't rewrite from the proxy. So can't imagine what to do :(

Comment: This just merged PR might help https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/commit/bd6d732fc71e4b4af9b9ba27aa30398bb3ddfbb0

Comment: That is a commit, it is merged. It's not released yet, but it is in master.