# How to Change the ServletPath in HttpServlet Requset

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httprequest, servlet-filters, spring-cloud

is There any way to rewrite `ServletPath` of `HttpServletRequest` in

> Spring boot/ Spring cloud?

for ex:

I can get servlet path using a filter from `HttpServletRequest` as follows.

```
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
request.getServletPath();
```

But I have to rewrite it (change it?).

Any Ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to achieve as the servlet path cannot be changed

Comment: this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449910/spring-cloud-zuul-reverse-proxy-doesnt-fetch-data-from-couchdb-when-url-encoded question. 

the requests that forwarding from my web application are decoded. I have to fix them (have to re encoded). So I need to change servlet path.